# How to avoid caching a child collection?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using *org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable* to cache de result of a method.
The method returns a List of entities. Each entity has some String attributes and a collection.

Is there a way to cache all the attributes avoiding the collection?
My idea is to manage that collection with hibernate cache.

Thanks!

Comment: Question needs an example

Comment: Is pretty simple:
An entity with two string attr and one collection.
The method returns a list of entities with all attributes cached... I need the entity list with only the string attr cached.

Comment: Entity structure is clear. What does "The method returns a list of entities with all attributes cached" mean? What are these cached against?